# Adding a checkbox to the card structure

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a to-do app that looks like this but I want to put a checkbox to the left of the texts. I'm trying to use the checkbox structure for this, but I can't add it because child is already full, how can I add a checkbox to the left in the card design. Using row or column doesn't work it really causes too many errors.

[image]

```
         Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: allTodo.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: Text("New ToDo"),
                          content: Container(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Form(
                                  key: _formKey,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      buildForm(_controllerTitle, "")
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: const Text(
                                "Cancel",
                              ),
                            ),
                            buildButton(Colors.indigo, updateObject),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                    _controllerTitle.text = allTodo[index].title;
                    clickedTodoID = allTodo[index].id!;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  title: Text(allTodo[index].title),
                  trailing: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      if (allTodo[index].id != null) {
                        _deleteTodo(allTodo[index].id!, index);
                        setState(() {});
                      } else {
                        print("id is null, cant perform Delete operation");
                      }
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Please post code as text rather than as a image

Comment: I added it as code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use leading, add checkbox widget here.

```
 Expanded(
  child: ListTile(
    //This one 
    leading: Checkbox(),
    title: Text('List Tile'),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I can't mark it as correct because time hasn't passed, but I will